# Read Partial Parquet file

Tags: c++, apache, buffer, parquet, partial

I have a Parquet file and I don't want to read the whole file into memory. I want to read the metadata and then read the rest of the file on demand. That is, for example, I want to read the second page of the first column in the third-row group. How would I do that using Apache Parquet cpp library? I have the offset of the part that I want to read from the metadata and can read it directly from the disk. Is there any way to pass that buffer to Apache Parquet library to uncompress, decode and iterate through the values? How about the same thing for column chunk or row groups? Basically, I want to read the file partially and then pass it to the parquet APIs to process it as opposes to give the file handler to the API and let it go through the file. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible by writing code. Please provide your approach and we can help you. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: I know it is possible by writing code! I was wondering if the library already supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scences this is what the Apache Parquet C++ library actually does. When you pass in a file handle, it will only read the parts it needs to. As it requires the file footer (the main metadata) to know where to find the segments of data, this will always be read. The data segments will only be read once you request them.

No need to write special code for this, the library already has it built-in. Thus, if you want to know in fine detail on how this is working, you only need to read the source of the library: https://github.com/apache/arrow/tree/master/cpp/src/parquet

Comment: Even though the library doesn't read the whole file  it needs the file to be passed to it. What I need is to pass only a portion of a file (a memory buffer) because I don't have access to the full parquet file. Is there a way to pass just a portion of a file (not the file handle) to the library?

Comment: thanks for the response, now i got what you meant and found the place for the code.

Comment: Cool! Just to clarify this for further readers: When you only have the portions of the file but have code that can request the remaining data, you can implement the File API by yourself and then retrieve the remaining data once the Parquet library asks for it.